# Counting page views using “impressionist” gem Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using impressionist gem to count each page impression from people who seen article page but the problem is that i get it only work for one article and the counter for the other are for 0

this is my code

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable
end

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash]
end
```

This is my show action

```
<%= "#{@article.impressionist_count} views" %>
```

Comment: please paste your show action code

Comment: def show
  @article = Article.find
  impressionist(@article)
end

Comment: the code u pasted is view code .. i want code in your controller ..

Comment: class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash]
end    def show

  end

Comment: it work now thank you but it is possible use booth method in controller impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash] and def show @article = Article.find impressionist(@article) end

Comment: that what i posted in my above comment . :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code in your controller ..

```
def show
   @article = Article.find
   impressionist(@article)
end
```

Comment: it work now thank you but it is possible use booth method in controller impressionist actions: [:show], unique: [:session_hash] and def show @article = Article.find impressionist(@article) end

Comment: Good answer however I would add `(params[:id])` at the end of `@article = Article.find(params[:id])`